# jQuery assign value to a variable, depending on the state of a checkbox, for submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery to validate the fields in a form and then populate a variable, depending on whether or not a checkbox is checked, so I can submit the data to a java program. The similar logic above it works; however, it stops after the "alert (5)" (i.e., does not reach "alert("5a")" or "alert("5b)")". I have included the HTML for the checkboxes after in case they are part of the issue (you can select "All" (the first checkbox being checked, i.e., after "alert (5)") or one or more of the other 8 checkboxes - which are in two rows).

There is no error in the console.

I have done a search through the HTML code to ensure the class, id and name do not occur elsewhere.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class=" bg-warning col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-2" style="border:solid black;">
            <div class="form-group" style="display: block;">
                <label class="control-label col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" for="attendance" style="line-height:50px">Attendance:<span class="req"> *</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="controls col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                <label class="checkbox-inline" for="attendanceAllCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="attendanceAll" value="All" id="attendanceAllCBs" name="attendanceAllCBs[]">All</label>
            </div>

            <div class=" col-lg-9 col-xs-9 col-sm-9">
                <div id="top">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline col-lg-2" for="attendanceOtherCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="attendance2" value="Friday" id="attendanceOtherCBs" name="attendanceOtherCBs[]">Friday</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline col-lg-2" for="attendanceOtherCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="attendance2" value="Saturday" id="attendanceOtherCBs" name="attendanceOtherCBs[]">Saturday</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline col-lg-2" for="attendanceOtherCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="attendance2" value="Sunday" id="attendanceOtherCBs" name="attendanceOtherCBs[]">Sunday</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="attendanceOtherCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="attendance2" value="DaysOnly" id="attendanceOtherCBs" name="attendanceOtherCBs[]">Days Only</label>
                </div>
                <div id="bottom">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline col-lg-2" for="attendanceOtherCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="attendance2" value="FridayNight" id="attendanceOtherCBs" name="attendanceOtherCBs[]">Friday Night</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline col-lg-2" for="attendanceOtherCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="attendance2" value="SaturdayNight" id="attendanceOtherCBs" name="attendanceOtherCBs[]">Saturday Night</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline col-lg-2" for="attendanceOtherCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="attendance2" value="SundaydayNight" id="attendanceOtherCBs" name="attendanceOtherCBs[]">Sundayday Night</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="attendanceOtherCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="attendance2" value="Other" id="attendanceOtherCBs" name="attendanceOtherCBs[]">Other</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
         alert(4);
         var gender = '';
         if (genderCBs[0].checked === true){
             gender = "M"
         }else{
             gender = "F"
         }
         alert(5);
         var attendanceAllvar = '';
         if (attendanceAllCBs[0].checked === true){
             alert("5a");
             attendanceAllvar = "Y";
         }else{
             alert("5b");
             attendanceAllvar = "N";
         }
         alert(6);
         var attendanceFriday = '';
         if(attendanceOtherCBs[0].checked === true){
             attendanceFriday = "Y";
         }else{
             attendanceFriday = "N";
         }
```

The following works:

HTML:

```
<div class="controls col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
    <span class="req"> *</span><label class="checkbox-inline" for="genderCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="gender" value="M" id="genderCBs" name="genderCBs[]">Male</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="genderCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="gender" value="F" id="genderCBs" name="genderCBs[]">Female</label>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
alert(4);
var gender = '';
if (genderCBs[0].checked === true){
    gender = "M"
}else{
    gender = "F"
}
```

Comment: Please create snippet

Comment: if it stops working after `alert(5)` which is also when you can "select `All` checkboxes", then thats prolly whats causing the issue

Comment: we are going to have to see more code than that to figure out whats causing the issue

Comment: I am sorry, I am a novice and do not know how to create a snippet.

Comment: Yes the error, I believe, is with the  "select All checkboxes" HTML. However, I can not figure out what the error is.

Comment: go to codepen.com or jsfiddle.com, then copy and paste the minimum amount of code required to reproduce the issue. save it and share the link with us

Comment: we cant figure out either until u share more of your code with us...

Comment: How much other code do you need please. Both the js and html are rather long so where can I put them for access?

Comment: Enough code to reproduce the problem and no more. i already told you, jsfiddle.com or codepen.com

Comment: The jsfiddle link took me to a site that triggered my antivirus and a voice alert that I had been infected by a virus that was sending my details to an unknown ip address!

Comment: myb jsfiddle.net. u have to tag ppl in your comments to otherwise we wont know if youve responded. you do this by placing a `@` and then the username i.e. @Glyn or whatever the person's username is

Comment: ID can't be same in HTML You used same id for all radio button..!!

Comment: Can u please Provide Full code of jQuery So that i can Help you

Comment: @PrakashChoudhary is right. thats at least one issue with your!! the same value for the `class` attribute can used for multiple elements, whereas each element must have a unique value for its `id` attribute

Comment: The issue with the link was: https://chooottttthiiiichooottttttt.oss-ap-southeast-2.aliyuncs.com/aws.html?num=1300-898-951

Comment: @PrakashChoudhary I had a similar issue with gender which I fixed by making the ids the same as per code I found elsewhere.

Comment: @Glyn please See Code which i answered will help you

Comment: @Glyn what is genderCBs in your js code ?

Comment: @PrakashChoudhary I have updated the original query with the working code.

Comment: @Glyn try with IDs and make IDs different different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :-

HTML:-

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class=" bg-warning col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-2" style="border:solid black;">
                <div class="form-group" style="display: block;">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" for="attendance" style="line-height:50px">Attendance:<span class="req"> *</span></label>
                </div>
                <div class="controls col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="attendanceAllCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="attendanceAll" value="All" id="attendanceAllCBs" name="attendanceAllCBs[]">All</label>
                </div>

                <div class=" col-lg-9 col-xs-9 col-sm-9">
                    <div id="top">
                       <label class="checkbox-inline col-lg-2" for="attendanceOtherCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="attendance2" value="Friday" id="attendanceFriday" name="attendanceOtherCBs[]">Friday</label>
                        <label class="checkbox-inline col-lg-2" for="attendanceOtherCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="attendance2" value="Saturday" id="attendanceSaturday" name="attendanceOtherCBs[]">Saturday</label>
                        <label class="checkbox-inline col-lg-2" for="attendanceOtherCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="attendance2" value="Sunday" id="attendanceSunday" name="attendanceOtherCBs[]">Sunday</label>
                        <label class="checkbox-inline" for="attendanceOtherCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="attendance2" value="DaysOnly" id="attendanceDaysOnly" name="attendanceOtherCBs[]">Days Only</label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="bottom">
                        <label class="checkbox-inline col-lg-2" for="attendanceOtherCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="attendance2" value="FridayNight" id="FridayNight" name="attendanceOtherCBs[]">Friday Night</label>
                        <label class="checkbox-inline col-lg-2" for="attendanceOtherCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="attendance2" value="SaturdayNight" id="SaturdayNight" name="attendanceOtherCBs[]">Saturday Night</label>
                        <label class="checkbox-inline col-lg-2" for="attendanceOtherCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="attendance2" value="SundaydayNight" id="SundaydayNight" name="attendanceOtherCBs[]">Sundayday Night</label>
                        <label class="checkbox-inline" for="attendanceOtherCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="attendance2" value="Other" id="Other" name="attendanceOtherCBs[]">Other</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    jQuery:

             alert(4);
             var gender = '';

             alert(5);
             var attendanceAllvar = '';
             if ($('#attendanceAllCBs').prop('checked') === true){
                 alert("5a");
                 attendanceAllvar = "Y";
             }else{
                 alert("5b");
                 attendanceAllvar = "N";
             }
             alert(6);
             var attendanceFriday = '';
             if($('#attendanceFriday').prop('checked') === true){
                 attendanceFriday = "Y";
             }else{
                 attendanceFriday = "N";
             }
```

Comment: <div class="controls col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
    <span class="req"> *</span><label class="checkbox-inline" for="genderCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="gender" value="M" id="genderMale" name="genderCBs[]">Male</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="genderCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="gender" value="F" id="genderFemale" name="genderCBs[]">Female</label>
</div>

alert(4);
var gender = '';
if ($('#genderMale').prop('checked') === true){
    gender = "M"
}else{
    gender = "F"
}

Comment: Hi Prakash, this works I will go through it line by line to see where you made the changes :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
  <div class="controls col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <span class="req"> *</span><label class="checkbox-inline" for="genderCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="gender" value="M" id="genderMale" name="genderCBs[]">Male</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline" for="genderCBs"><input type="checkbox" class="gender" value="F" id="genderFemale" name="genderCBs[]">Female</label>
    </div>

    alert(4);
    var gender = '';
    if ($('#genderMale').prop('checked') === true){
    alert(5);
        gender = "M"
    }else{
    alert(6);
        gender = "F"
    }
```